# Is work able to force me to install software on personal equipment?

Tags: canada, business

Due to the corona-virus around the world, like so many others I am working from home as possible.

Work has just decided that because of this, we should be using Mircosoft Teams to help us all communicate as a team. I have no work equipment outside the office, so this would mean having to install it on my personal phone. Which I am not wanting to do. I have read tales from online where using personal equipment for work has lead to issues (remote wipes, who owns the data, who has rights to the equipment, ...).

As I live and work in Canada, and have not agreed to use my personal equipment for work, is there any way they are allowed to force me to do so or to react to my refusal?

Comment: It will not lead to issues by itself, so I dont see the problem. They cannot force you to do anything, they can just fire you so it's up to you.

Comment: This doesn't really address the legal issues in question, which is kind of the point of this board.

Comment: Threes no legal issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the owner of your own computer, you can dispose of it however you see fit (as long as your choice is legal). The courts could, theoretically, force you do do something with your computer, but installing software is not one of the things that the courts are empowered to force you to do. (Mostly, they can force you to turn it over for a search). A company can't force you to do anything with your property: only the courts can order the use of force. But there is no legal basis for the courts to grant a company's request for an order to install software.

A company can perhaps *persuade* you to install software on your personal computer, in exchange for keeping your employment. I assume you are familiar with the law regarding firing people. If you do not perform your job, you might be terminated for cause. You could hire an attorney and sue for wrongful dismissal, and it's not obvious that you have a valid reason for non-performance. So I would suggest consulting a Canadian employment attorney before sticking your neck too far out.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I knew/suspected but I didnt have any actual ground to stand on.

Comment: If the situation is: You can't work in the office, you have to work from home. You have to install this software in order to be able to work from home. Refusal means you cannot work. In that case the company may have the right to send you on enforced holiday first and then lay you off or pay you for the hours you are working, which are zero.